# Retaining parts of the dataframe depending on the values in the column of the same dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
A    B     C    D     E    F
A3   25    26   A1    36    39
A3   10    10   A4    10    10
A5   66   22    A2    26    26
A6   66   26    A3    35    36
A7   34   36    A5    66    22
```

I want to retain part of the dataframe depending on the value of column A. This I want an output like this: (PLEASE NOTE that the sum of ColB and ColC with same ColA values is equal already to the ColE and ColF).

```
A    B     C    D     E    F
A3   25    26   A3    35    36
A3   10    10   A5    66    22
A5   66   22    NA    NA    NA
A6   66   26    NA    NA    NA
A7   34   36    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is not clear what is the logical condition that should keep the data... But it should be pretty easy to set NaNs values that do not satisfy a condition, e.g. `df.loc[df['A'] != 'A3', 'D'] = np.nan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter rows from list `c` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), create default index and append to original `DataFrame` without `c` columns:

```
c = ['D','E','F']
df = df.drop(c, axis=1).join(df.loc[df['D'].isin(df['A']), c].reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
    A   B   C    D     E     F
0  A3  25  26   A3  35.0  36.0
1  A3  10  10   A5  66.0  22.0
2  A5  66  22  NaN   NaN   NaN
3  A6  66  26  NaN   NaN   NaN
4  A7  34  36  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Or:

```
c = ['D','E','F']

m = df['D'].isin(df['A'])
df.loc[~m, c] = np.nan

df = df.sort_values(c, key=lambda x: x.isna())
print (df)
    A   B   C    D     E     F
3  A6  66  26   A3  35.0  36.0
4  A7  34  36   A5  66.0  22.0
0  A3  25  26  NaN   NaN   NaN
1  A3  10  10  NaN   NaN   NaN
2  A5  66  22  NaN   NaN   NaN
```